# unable to set header in php and send email from cpanel

Tags: php, cpanel

I am unable to set header in php for from address I have tried all possible values :

The code below is correct but code is not attached to header .

It shows this as default from but does not change.

```
From :  webhost:cpanel@hosting
```

Is this the problem with cpanel ?

Please help me out really appreciate the help.

Thanks in Advance.

```
<?php

$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$phone = $_REQUEST['contact'];

$subject = "feedback";
$question = $_REQUEST['question'];


$body = "<html>
<head>

</html>";
$mime_boundary = "<<<--==+X[".md5(time())."]\r\n\r\n";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n" ."Content-Type:text/html;"."\r\n";
$headers .= 'From:'.$email. "\r\n";


$to ='example@example.com';
mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
echo "<script>alert(' message  sent.');</script>";

?>
```

also tried :

```
<?php
$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: Sender Name <sender@domain.com>";
   $headers[] = "Reply-To: Recipient Name <receiver@domain3.com>";
$headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $email, implode("\r\n", $headers));
?>
```

Only this works:

```
    $to ='example@example.com';
$subject="subject";
$body="body";
    $mime_boundary = "<<<--==+X[".md5(time())."]\r\n\r\n";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n" ."Content-Type:text/html;"."\r\n";
    mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
```

Comment: why not just trying to send simple mail?

Comment: added code above if the header has reply and from then I can respond and so can the user else the user cannot respond/reply back as the cpanel webhost account name will not have an email account and hence delivery will fail. I would like to replace header from name with my own id thats all !!

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
$to = 'me@gmail.com';

$subject = "Email from me by: John";
$body = "my body";
$headers = "From: "."hello@world.com"."\r\n" .
"Reply-To: "."hello@world.com"."\r\n".
 "X-Mailer: php";
 $sent=mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

if ($sent) {

 echo "good!";

} else {
echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
}
```

Comment: Message delivery failed... No idea why ??

Comment: then im sure the problem is on the server, i gave you a working production code, maybe the "mail" is not installed on the server

Comment: $to ='example@example.com';
$subject="subject";
$body="body";
    $mime_boundary = "<<<--==+X[".md5(time())."]\r\n\r\n";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n" ."Content-Type:text/html;"."\r\n";
    mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);   this is working so mail works.

Comment: is there any setting I need to change??

Comment: i cant understand, did you managed ? or not? what is still not working?

Comment: No Still stuck with the same issue.Unable to set from/reply header ,subject header is working !!Thanks for asking.